# Can I operate different tasks in same ISR sorting by interrupt flag?

Tags: c, linux, interrupt, sensors, interrupt-handling

I'm on my IOT project with raspberry pi.

I'm building kernel module using PIR sensor.

I want to do this :

when PIR get RISING signal, global variable `count` increases every second.

and do some action when `count` == 5

if FALLING signal appears before `count` become 5, `count` reset to `0`

So, I may need flag data in ISR function like below,

but I cannot find function or syscall for that.

Could you help me?

> global scope

```
static struct timer_list my_timer;
#define LED1 4
#define SENSOR1 17
static int count = 0;
static int irq_num;
```

> module init

```
static int __init module_init(void)
{
    int ret;


    gpio_request_ont(SENSOR1, GPIOF_IN, "sensor1");

    irq_num = gpio_to_irq(SENSOR1);

    ret = request_irq(irq_num, pir, IRQF_TRIGGER_RISING | IRQF_TRIGGER_FALLING, "sensor_irq", NULL);

    if(ret)
    {
        printk(KERN_ERR "Unable to request IRQ : %d\n", ret);
        free_irq(irq_num, NULL);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

> ISR function

```
static irqreturn_t pir(int irq, void *data)
{
    gpio_request_one(LED1, GPIOF_OUT_INIT_LOW, "led1");
    gpio_set_value(LED1, 0);

    //pseudo code
    if(flag == RISING)
    {
        init_timer(&my_timer);

        my_timer.function = my_timer_func;
        my_timer.data = LED1;
        my_timer.expires = jiffies + (1 * HZ);

        add_timer(&my_timer);
    }
    else if(flag == FALLING)
    {
        count = 0;
    }

    return IRQ_HANDLED;
}
```

> timer function

```
static void my_timer_func(unsigned long data)
{
    count ++;

    if(count == 5)
    {
        gpio_set_value(LED1, 1);  //actions that I want will be here
        count = 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: take a look at [`del_timer`](https://www.kernel.org/doc/htmldocs/device-drivers/API-del-timer.html) to stop and delete timer when signal is falling

Comment: @Garf365 that can help me! but do you mean that I should make two isr for one sensor?

Comment: No, I just think you have to add `del_timer(&my_timer);` just before `count = 0;` from ISR. It will stop timer and so, stop increasing `count`

Comment: but.. how can I know which flag causes ISR? I mean how can I know what is `flag` in the code?

Comment: Oooo OK,  I didn't understood... you can create this flag by memorising previous value of gpio and compare it to current value: previous on and current off => falling; previous off and actual on => rising. Or you can create two handler, one for rising, another one for failing. Use last parameter of irq_request to identify each to remove later one or other or both

Comment: Thanks very much! your comment really helps me